# how to use a cron job to upload to s3 bucket using awscli?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron, aws-cli

I'm trying to upload a folder to s3 bucket every 5 minutes. I have configured the cron using `crontab`

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin

*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/bigbluebutton.sh
```

And the script I'm using look like this

```
aws s3 cp /var/bigbluebutton/published/presentation s3://testbucket/ --recursive --region us-west-2
```

But it does not upload the folder.
The command works perfectly when run in terminal. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any errors or messages in the logs from the `crontab` process? You can probably find them using: `grep -r cron /etc/*syslog*`

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: What is the output from `/bin/ls -la /usr/local/bin/bigbluebutton.sh`?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124 Jun 27 18:40 /usr/local/bin/bigbluebutton.sh

Comment: What happens after you do this: `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/bigbluebutton.sh` and then let your cron job run? (You may have to do this thus: `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/bigbluebutton.sh`).

Comment: That solved the issue! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

give full path to aws, first find "aws" full path
$ which aws
/usr/local/bin/aws

now write/run below command, uploading will be working good.

sudo /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp

Comment: Please consider rewriting your answer to cover how to use the aws CLI in a cron job.  Your answer never mentions cron, so it probably cannot answer the question.  (Not sure why it should sudo, either).

Comment: our cron job now working, uploading data to our bucket, when i give full path to "aws".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `aws s3 cp` use `aws s3 sync` in script.

```
echo "Commencing S3 /data backup `date`" >> /var/log/backups/s3-data-sync.log

/usr/bin/aws s3 sync /data s3://linux123-backup-skhvynirme --exclude '*.log*' >> /var/log/backups/s3-data-sync.log 2>&1

echo "Completed S3 /data backup `date`" >> /var/log/backups/s3-data-sync.log
```